# How to fix "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path (...): UUID

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sqlite, maven, spring-data-jpa

I have this error when running a springboot app:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: UUID
```

I tried to troubleshot this issue but I only find pages describing a similar issue but with "Invocation of init method failed" instead "UUID".

"UUID" is not where to be found when it comes to the "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource" error message :/

chatGPT is telling me:
"The org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException you're encountering with the message "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'" typically indicates an issue with the configuration of the entityManagerFactory bean, which is responsible for managing the JPA (Java Persistence API) entity manager in a Spring Boot application.

The error message includes a reference to the HibernateJpaConfiguration.class and the term "UUID." This suggests that there might be a mismatch in the versions of the libraries you are using, especially related to Hibernate."

This makes a lot of sense however I have double checked all compatibility on maven repository and it looks I am up to date.
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.globomatics</groupId>
    <artifactId>bike</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bike</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>3.1.3</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Other dependencies -->

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SQLite Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.42.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Moreover, I fail to understand this "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'" since I am using spring data jpa repository and I don't have to configure entityManagerFactory nor datasource in this case.

Here is also my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:bike.db
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Also some information on my annotations that should be correct:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.globomatics.bike.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.globomatics.bike.repositories")
public class BikeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BikeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/bikes")
public class BikeController {

    private final BikeRepository bikeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BikeController(BikeRepository bikeRepository) {
        this.bikeRepository = bikeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Bike> list() {
        return bikeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@RequestBody Bike bike){
        bikeRepository.save(bike);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Bike get(@PathVariable("id") long id){

        return bikeRepository.getReferenceById(id);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Bike {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String model;
    private String serialNumber;
    private BigDecimal purchasePrice;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
    private Date purchaseDate;
    private boolean contact;

// GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

finally, standard JPA repo interface:

```
public interface BikeRepository extends JpaRepository <Bike, Long> {

}
```

This is from the following class: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/building-first-app-with-spring-boot-angularjs/table-of-contents

The content was poorly updated in the past few years. And I am trying to implement the main changes since springboot 3.0++ considering some major dependency migrations.

Some dependency compatibilies might be the cause of the issue.

Also the error "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'" is terribly misleading to me as mentioned above.

So after 2 days between searches, docs, mvn clean install, trials and errors, random guessing between versionning and chatgpt, I drop a message here asking for help.

Thanks a lot.

Charles

Comment: run `mvn dependency:tree` and check if you have some imports from `javax`. It would be first step if I got the same problem.

Comment: also remove maven dependency `hibernate-core` and `jakarta.persistence-api` because `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already provide these as transient one.

Comment: Good point: "mvn dependency:tree" meets a "build:success". I have removed hibernate-core and jakarta.persistence-api since indeed these are included in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Comment: the error still exist ?

Comment: It has changed: 

´´´
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
´´´ 
I am digging

Comment: So it suggests that my "spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect"  in my application.properties file is not recognized. And it makes little sense since it is what is clearly defined in several tutorials and documentations

Comment: Also I tried this solution unsuccessfuly => https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sqlite-not-working-with-hibernate-6-2/8174 which is replacing hibernate-core by hibernate-community. the error stays the same with "community" in it => "Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect]".

Comment: Just add it to `pom.xml` as dependency [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gwenn/sqlite-dialect/0.1.4)

Comment: It seems it is not compatible with the dependency versions in my pom.xml, furthermore, when I build, maven seems not to be happy with that:

Comment: [WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.globomatics:bike:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.github.gwenn:sqlite-dialect:jar -> version 0.1.4 vs 0.1.1 @ line 56, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]

Comment: there is version problem you could set latest one that is `0.1.4` I guess also  did it solve the main problem ?

Comment: however when I put this dependency (0.1.4) I see that when starting it's trying to search in the right path in my local .m2 repo. I get another error. I feel we're almost here

Comment: what is that another error ?

Comment: The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect: file:/C:/Users/CharlesJulien/.m2/repository/com/github/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/0.1.4/sqlite-dialect-0.1.4.jar
    org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: file:/C:/Users/CharlesJulien/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.2.7.Final/hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar
Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect

Comment: and I updated "spring.jpa.database-platform=org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" in my application.properties, so that it looks for the right thing

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally solved this.

**1) Hibernate community is key**

First it is important to understand that since Hibernate 6+, sqlite dialect has been moved from "hibernate core" to "hibernate community dialect". This was supported in some of my research:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite

https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/varargssqlfunction-was-deleted-hibernate-6-0s-development/6826

So I had to add explicitly

1. the dependency "hibernate-community^-dialect" in my pom.xml
2. add in application.properties: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect`

At that point, unlike previously, my project will build successfuly. However I will still fail to start.

**2) Hibernate core is in sping data jpa and must be excluded**

Second, Spring Data JPA includes Hibernate as its default JPA provider. In my case "spring-data-jpa" includes "Hibernate core 6.2.7.FINAL". This one is used by default when you run your app and springboot is looking for sqlite dialect in Hibernate core, which does not exist.

So the trick here is to to add an exclusion of hibernate core to your spring data jpa dependency in your pom.xml

To summarize, you'll find my pom and my application.properties.

```
# Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect

# Datasource config for Sqlite
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:bike.db
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.globomatics</groupId>
    <artifactId>bike</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bike</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>3.1.3</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Other dependencies -->

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SQLite Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.44.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```